# Read a file form web-app

Tags: grails

Inside a grails application, I need to upload a file under web-app/js, add a prefix, and put it in S3. I'm having trouble figuring out how to read the js file in a way that will work in development (/web-app/js) and production (/js). I'm doing this from inside a domain object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controllers, you can call :

```
def jsFolder = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("js/").getFile()
```

and then proceed with `jsFolder`.
To determine the base directory of a running Grails application, use

```
String dir = applicationContent.getResource("/").getFile()
```

Getting the js path from a service is a little bit tricky:

You need to implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface like this :

```
class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {
ApplicationContext applicationContext
```

However, calling this code from a domain class is not a good idea (see this [thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Resolving-app-s-resources-path-from-Domain-class-td1388510.html) for some explanations) and I am not even sure if it's possible except from getting paths from manual configurations

Hope it helps.