# Reading XML file from the application in Groovy service class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have placed my static XML file inside `web-app/<my_custom_folder>/<my_xml_file.xml>`
Now, from the groovy service class, I want to read the file and parse it.
How do I access the file and what is the class I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply open the file and parse it via

```
def testXml = new XmlSlurper().parse('web-app/<my_custom_folder>/<my_xml_file.xml>')
```

Note that the path is relative to the root of your Grails project.

Examples on how to use the resulting `testXml` variable can be found [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)

---

Edit: If you plan to deploy your application using a war file, you should consider moving your XML file to another location, as the web-app directory will not be available anymore, but your could do what you want using an absolute path, an environment variable or the ClassPath.

If you are looking for a way to configure your application, you should read the chapter on [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration)  in the manual.

Thanks to @Burt Beckwith for pointing this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Will it work if i directly use as u mentioned? I have a folder created inside web-app/myfolder/my.xml. Can i use new XmlSlurper().parseText('web-app/myfolder/my.xml') ?

Comment: I got the below error during xml parsing. [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Can you tel me why the error occured? i am suspecting it could be because of the the xml file format!

Comment: It looks like your XML file is not correctly formed. Check your syntax with a validator.

Comment: This won't work in a deployed war, since there's no web-app folder in the war.

Comment: For the war file part of this, you might look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573812/read-a-file-form-web-app) for ideas. Antoine is right, though, that the file ought to probably be somewhere else. Perhaps someplace already on the CLASSPATH (`WEB-INF/classes`, for example).